# Does CentOS 6 have Xen-compatible Kernel?

Tags: centos, virtualization, amazon-ec2, centos6, paravirtualization

I would to try to convert my VirtualBox image and upload to Amazon EC2, following this tutorial:

http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/1246/converting-from-virtualbox-or-vmware-to-ec2-now-easier-than-ever/

However, the operating system which I installed in my virtual machine is a minimal install ISO of CentOS 6, and I don't know if it have a Xen-compatible kernel. So, before proceding with that tutorial, I must know:

1. If I need to grab a EC2 compatible kernel, and where I can get it
2. If I have to build a kernel mysef and how D:

Answer (score 3):

Xen runs on RHEL6 & CentOS6. RedHat does not support this, but Xen still strives to run on RHEL6.

See http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/RHEL6Xen4Tutorial for a tutorial and a list of required RPMs. This tutorial says:

> As a default RHEL6 does NOT:
>
> - RHEL6 does not ship Xen hypervisor or tools.
> - RHEL6 does not ship Xen dom0 capable kernel.
>
> As a default RHEL6 DOES:
>
> - RHEL6 runs as Xen PV (paravirtual) domU using the pvops framework in the default kernel.
> - RHEL6 runs as Xen HVM (fully virtualized) guest.
> - RHEL6 ships with optimized Xen PV-on-HVM drivers for RHEL6 Xen HVM guests.